# ng-web-apis Geolocation error in node_modules

Tags: angular, geolocation

I am working on a project with Angular 9, and I installed the Geolocation API from [https://github.com/ng-web-apis/geolocation](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) and added some code to get my current location.

After installing the package, I run my project and this is the error I encountered.

```
*
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ng-web-apis/geolocation/fesm2015/ng-web-apis-geolocation.js 33:233-251
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ng-web-apis/geolocation/fesm2015/ng-web-apis-geolocation.js 35:0-27
export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ng-web-apis/geolocation/fesm2015/ng-web-apis-geolocation.js 33:26-47
export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ng-web-apis/geolocation/fesm2015/ng-web-apis-geolocation.js 34:27-51
export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'**
```

I tried reinstalling the node_modules and nothing happened.

These are the details of my angular project.

```
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 9.0.7
Node: 14.18.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.0.7
... cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.15
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.15
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.0.7
@angular/animations               9.1.13
@angular/cdk                      9.2.4
@angular/fire                     5.4.2
@angular/material                 9.2.4
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.15
@nguniversal/builders             9.1.1
@nguniversal/common               9.1.1
@nguniversal/express-engine       9.1.1
@schematics/angular               9.0.7
@schematics/update                0.900.7
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.7.7
webpack                           4.42.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm update @ng-web-apis/geolocation
```

If updating the library does not fix the issue, you might want to try uninstalling and reinstalling the library to see if that helps. You can do this by running the following commands:

```
npm uninstall @ng-web-apis/geolocation
npm install @ng-web-apis/geolocation
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but still it doesn't work for me. I think the problem would be the Angular version of my project is not compatible with the api.